# Accessing a PHP(xampp) page on local machine from Android

Tags: php, android

I was trying to access a localhost page using 192.168.56.1.
which was working fine yesterday on my emulator as well as in my device .

But today when I tried, it is not working I am getting timeout information in device ; but still works perfectly in emulator. I couldnt figure out what went wrong as I didnt changed any settings or nothing.

I have also ensured INTERNET permission in manifest file .Also in IPCONFIG i have checked I am referring to the correct ip address. I am using XAMPP as the server.

Could you please guide as what went wrong ?

Comment: What is 192.168.56.1? Is that the IP of your router and you are port fowarding to the xampp server? Is that the IP of your xampp server?

Comment: That is the IPV4 address shown in my IPCONFIG

Comment: Actually my desktop is in another LAN n/w and i have disabled the Firewall security of my machine. The phone device I am getting internet via the SIM card. So I hope both of them are on different networks. So does it mean that until and unless i brought them to the same n/w (using WIFI )i cant connect the server page from phone ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above: The IP you are trying to go to on your phone (192.168.56.1) is a local IP for your LAN. You can't actually go to that IP while on the internet since it's only known to the other computers that are on your same LAN. Since your phone is not connected to the LAN then it won't be able to see that computer via that IP address.

If your computer is hooked up to a router, then you need to do some port forwarding on the router. If this is an internet application (http) then you need forward Port 80 to your computer's LAN IP of 192.168.56.1. After that change you'll be able to point your phone to the IP assigned to your by your ISP. You can find this by going to http://www.whatsmyip.org/ on your desktop computer.

Your external IP address will send your phone to your router which will forward HTTP traffic (port 80) to your internal Desktop ip address of 192.168.56.1.